# Two pages grabbing click event on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad

I have a website I have written which is cross platform. On the iPad I have to use the mouseup and mouseup events to simulate a click (because it is events imbedded within SVG inside an iFrame and there are special events if someone presses and holds, or presses and drags or presses and releases (clicks))

Here is what is happening.
touchStart event triggered.
touchEnd event triggered.
My script sees that this is a click event and then triggers the following event:

window.parent.window.location.href = "../TRL/SelectHotspot.aspx" + returnString

The browser then goes to that page, but then (strange this...) the control that is in that exact position on the target page recieves a click event. This means that it then moves onto the next page.

Does anyone know what would cause this and how to stop it please? It doesn't happen on desktops (they don't expose the touchstart / touchend event anyway) and not on any android devices.

Comment: why not use touch events for ipad instead of mouseup and down? whats wrong?

Comment: Since iOS 4 it has had unexpected behaviour within Embed tags that contain embedded javascript.